# Methods to estimate a probability distribution from truncated data?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have a large set of values $t = \{t_i\}_{i=1}^N$. In actuality, these values (in some set of units) can range between $0$ and an unknown cutoff of the order of $10^7$, but they come from a numerical simulation which, due to memory issues, I have to downsample, so in the course of the simulation I have dropped all $t_i<5.0$.

I would like to calculate the cumulative probability that $t > T$. When I count the number of $t_i$ greater than $T$, and I plot it versus $T$, I get a nice looking truncated power law type distribution for the counts $N(t>T)$ across the variable $T$.

However, I cannot simply write $ P(t>T) = N(t>T)/N$, because I neglected very many values at $T<5.0$, and I should really be normalizing by the total number of my values, including those I neglected, rather than the size of my downsampled data.

That is, the largest value of $P(t>T)$ should happen at $T=0$, and not at $T=5.0$, which is where it would occur if I did it this way.

How can I handle a truncated dataset of this form? I need to calculate a histogram using the frequency of occurrence of values, but I have no means to normalize the counts, because I don't know how many values should actually exist if I hadn't truncated the data.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You actually can estimate $\mathsf{P}(t>T)$ for $T\ge 5$. Just divide by the total number of samples, including the neglected ones.

Comment: Do you have a specific power law in mind?

Comment: @d.k.o. unfortunately I can't determine the total number of neglected samples.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you choose $5.0$? Clearly you are losing critical information, and the data set you end up with is not a good sample. If you must downsize the sample, don't downsize it by choosing data truncated arbitrarily, but just choose a random sample which is small enough, if possible. This way you can hope to get a representing sample, which you evidently do not have now.

Comment: So you would suggest sampling the simulation as it runs at uniformly random intervals? A priori I don't see an unbiased way to do this either. I arbitrarily chose the sampling rate as $1/5$ as a compromise between memory and fine-grained resolution. I'm mostly interested in the tail of the cdf, so I thought this would be appropriate, but now I'm realizing I can't resolve the tails if I can't define the cdf from the relative frequencies.  I agree with you, the sample becomes biased. I can run the simulations again if I knew a better way to sample them as they run

Comment: I believe I could just sample at every $k$th transition, instead of ignoring a certain subset of transitions... does this seem reasonable?

It will be a bit difficult to pin down the memory requirements of each simulation condition-- that becomes the new issue.

Answer (score 1):

This question would be better asked at the [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) site.  However...

If you do have samples from a truncated power law distribution (as compared to a censored distribution where you knew how many observations were below 5), then you can certainly estimate the parameter for the non-truncated distribution *if you really know that the whole distribution follows the particular power law*.

Suppose the truncated distribution has probability density

$$f(x)=\frac{(k-1) x^{-k}}{5^{1-k}}$$

and you have samples $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$.  The maximum likelihood estimator of $k$ is

$$\hat{k}=(\overline{\log x}-\log 5 +1)/(\overline{\log x}-\log5)$$

where $\overline{\log x}=\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i/n$ (*i.e.*, mean of the logs).

Therefore the un-truncated distribution will have density function

$$g(x)=(k-1)x^{-k}$$

for $x\ge 1$ assuming that the lower bound is 1.  You mention a lower bound of $0$ but that particular power law density doesn't converge on the interval $(0,\infty)$.  So that's why I asked in my comment above if you had a particular (and specific) power law in mind.

An estimate of the standard error of $\hat{k}$ is

$$\sqrt{\frac{(\hat {k}-1)^2}{n}}$$

Comment: Thanks @JimB. The maximum likelihood estimator is instructive. My process is difficult to study analytically, and meant to represent a physical process whose outcome is experimentally uncertain. I suspect a truncated Pareto distribution (can google Aban et al 2006) at least fits the data, but I need a more clever sampling method in order to study it carefully, I think. I'll move to crossvalidated!

Comment: A quick glance at that paper (Alban et al 2006) seems to indicate only an upper bound truncation is considered when what you describe is a lower bound truncation.  Either or both is pretty simple to do.

Comment: The upper bound truncation is a natural result of the process, while the lower bound truncation is a relic of my $1/\Delta t$ sampling rate. Thanks ! MLE on a double truncated distribution is an option, but I think, given my uncertainty about the truncated Pareto form on the data, I need a more careful down-sampling method on the full time-series

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to restrict the number of stored transitions. Instead of dropping observations, you may store $k$'th observation with probability $0<p<1$. That is, let $X_k\sim\text{Bern}(p)$ independent of $t_k$. Then you store $t_k$ if $X_k=1$ and estimate $q_T:=\mathsf{P}(t>T)$ using
$$
\hat{q}_T=n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n 1\{t_k>T\}\times 1\{n>0\},
$$
where $n$ is the number of stored samples (note that $n\sim \text{Bin}(p,N)$ where $N$ is the (*unknown*) total number of observations). Assuming that each $t_k$ is an independent copy of $t$,
$$
\mathsf{E}\hat{q}_T=\sum_{l=1}^N l^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^l \mathsf{P}(t_k>T)\times \mathsf{P}(n=l)=\mathsf{P}(t>T)\times \mathsf{P}(n>0),
$$
which is very close to $\mathsf{P}(t>T)$ when $N$ is large.

On average you will need to store $pN$ observations with standard deviation $\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$.